# Google Contact API - 401 Client Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, google-contacts-api

I have a problem at Google Contact API. I am using follow code to fetch all contracts from google account.

But it always throws 401 error. anyone can help me please?

Thank you.

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {

    return;
}


if(!error) {

    auth.clientID  =  @"Cient ID";
    auth.clientSecret  = @"Client Secret";
    auth.scope= @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

    NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&alt=json&max-results=500";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
    [auth authorizeRequest:request
         completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
             NSString *output = nil;
             if (error) {
                 output = [error description];
             } else {
                 NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                                  error:&error];
                 if (data) {
                     // API fetch succeeded :Here I am getti
                     output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                     NSLog(@"%@",output);
                 } else {
                     // fetch failed
                     output = [error description];
                 }
             }
         }];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try like this But first you need to get `Accesstoken` from `GoogleOAuth` then try.

```
NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=10000&access_token=%@",[UserDefaults objectForKey:@"AccessToken"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
[request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *returnresponse = nil;
NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&returnresponse error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[GETReply bytes] length:[GETReply length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *jsonData = [theReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict11=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:jsonData error:nil];
```

Is in responce you will get `XML` data. so you want to parse `XML`.

I Hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: I used access token like this.

NSString* str = auth.accessToken;
NSString *urlStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&alt=json&max-results=500&access_token=%@",str];

but it still returns the same result.

Comment: Just add this line in YOUR CODE [request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; and then try u miss this line in your code

Comment: @adeltahir And remember first u need to get google authentication then after u will able to get contacts from google.